# Is past subjunctive necessary when using "il fallait que"

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

When translating "they had to find a way to do it" in a formal written text, I'm not sure whether or not to use the past subjunctive if the idea of past is already encoded in *il fallait que*.

The way I feel I would say this, at least in speech, is *il fallait qu'elles trouvent une façon de le faire* but I'm unsure if I should be using a past form of the subjunctive instead, such as *aient trouvé*.

My reasoning behind going for the first option rather than the second is that because the idea of past is already encoded once in *fallait*, including it in the subjunctive form again would suggest that from the point of reference (past), they already should have done it.

I hope I'm explaining this clearly enough; any help and explanations of why you should use one form over the other would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The same applies to the sentence in English: *Il fallait qu'elles trouvent une façon de le faire.* → "They had to find a way to do it".  *Il fallait qu'elles aient trouvé une façon de le faire.* → "They had to have found  a way to do it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be strictly in accordance with the grammatical rules, you should indeed also apply the **concordance des temps** with the subjunctive, therefore using either the **subjonctif imparfait** or the **subjonctif plus-que-parfait** for the simultaneity or the anteriority of the subordinate action, respectively.

This would thus be :

> il fallait qu'elles trouvassent ...
>
> il fallait que tu vinsses ...

**In practice**, as far as I can tell, most people use the **subjonctif présent** or the **subjonctif passé** instead, especially if you are speaking. So that you should not use the past forms when you speak if you don't want to sound old fashioned. I find it a little sad, but that's the way it is.

As a last remark,

> il fallait qu'elles aient trouvé...

would be interpreted as an action that took place before "il fallait" because the **subjonctif passé** replaces the **subjonctif plus-que-parfait** in this (wrong but admitted in practice) context.